# Should I redo this Pex-A fitting?

Tags: plumbing, pex

I'm new to Pex A.  I put this Tee together, and didn't get the line at the center of the tee seated fully before it gripped.  It is not leaking, and has been holding fine for 2 days.  Is it good enough; can I leave it like this?  Or does this need to be redone to prevent premature leak or failure?

[image: Pex A tee]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should "remove the tubing and ring from the fitting and trim 2 in. from the tubing. Using a new reinforcing ring, [try again]."

Tests certify the connection for 100±10 psi under the following procedure from ASTM F1960:

> 9.3.1 Assembly of Connections—Affix the cold expansion fitting to the PEX tubing by sliding the PEX reinforcing ring onto the tubing and positioning the ring so that the end of the ring overhangs the end of the tubing a maximum of 1⁄16 in. (1.6 mm). Insert the expansion head into the tubing as far as it will
> go. Holding the tool so that the centerline of the expansion head is approximately in line with the centerline of the tubing, operate the tool until the tubing and reinforcing ring are fully expanded. After completing the expansion process, remove the expansion tool and insert the cold expansion fitting until the tubing hits the shoulder of the fitting or the tube stop. Hold the fitting in place until the tubing contracts sufficiently to hold the
> fitting in place.
>
> 9.3.2 Improper Connections—If the insert fitting was not fully inserted to its shoulder or tube stop or the reinforcing ring was not placed in accordance with 9.3.1, remove the tubing and ring from the fitting and trim 2 in. from the tubing. Using a new reinforcing ring, repeat the procedure in 9.3.1.